# How to send data to the next page in addition to a form?

Tags: php, forms

How does one send additional data to the next page with php if there is already a form doing it? For example

```
<form action='blah.php?variable1=$var' method='post'>
 Example: <input type="text" name="example"><br>
</form>
```

Doesn't seem to direct to:

blah.php?variable1=thisVariable&example=thisExample

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to hand over the variable as hidden value:

```
<form action="blah.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="variable1" value="<?=$var?>">
    Example: <input type="text" name="example"><br>
</form>
```

For more complex situations you should use server side sessions to store such values, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming blah.php is in this same directory, suggest using `./` in front of the filename (not necessary, just suggested  but the main problem is `$var` won't get it's value printed in your code.  You can print it out with the short tag method, like this..

```
<form action='./blah.php?variable1=<?=$var?>' method='post'>
```

or, a plain PHP echo like this...

```
<form action='./blah.php?variable1=<?php echo $var;?>' method='post'>
```